# How can I make a macOS Mojave bootable USB installer in Windows 10?

Tags: macos, usb, mojave, install

I have downloaded and saved macOS Mojave installation file from the Mac App Store into my external hard drive. Unfortunately, macOS has crashed on my Mac and now I need to install it again. I have used a software named TransMac to make a installation USB in windows following the steps in the link below:

[I used this link](https://www.intowindows.com/create-macos-sierra-bootable-usb-drive-from-windows/)

But the provided USB drive after all these steps doesn't show up in my MacBook pro. Considering that I have saved `Install macOS Mojave.app` on my external hard drive, and I don't have access to any other Mac computers, How can I fix this issue and build a USB for installing Mojave?

Comment: I assume you know to hold down the option key immediately after starting the Mac. Hold until the Startup Manger icons appear.

Answer (score 2):

It is generally not possible to create a macOS bootable installer using Windows or Linux computer.

You can consider installing macOS via [Internet Recovery](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT201314).

Comment: I tried that option too, but it sticks in the middle of the process and doesn't work.

Comment: @Naser.Sadeghi What is the make and model of Mac that you are using?

Comment: MacBook Pro 2016

Comment: @Naser.Sadeghi How long does it remain stuck? Any error messages that you are getting?

Comment: It simply says an error occur while trying to recover ....

Comment: @Naser.Sadeghi Do you have a stable Internet connection? Alternatively, do you have an Apple Store in the vicinity?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to create Mojave USB installer on Windows with the app installer downloaded from Mac App Store. You have to download Mojave dmg file and burn it to USB. Unfortunately, there are only two Windows app that works in this way. One is TransMac and the other is UUByte DMG editor.

For those, who failed with TransMac, UUByte DMG Editor is good to go. The steps are much simpler than TransMac. Simply load the dmg file into the program, choose the USB for burning and finally start the burning process. It will be done within 10 minutes on an USB 3.0 drive.

Full tutorial is covered in here: [How to Create macOS Mojave Bootable USB on PC](https://www.uubyte.com/create-macos-mojave-bootable-usb-on-pc.html)

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to create a virtual machine on the pc that runs mac OS then create the bootable flash drive there.

You should be able to create the vm using the .app file (as long as it is the full .app, should be over 5gb) and some free downloads ie. Vmware, vmware unlocker....

How I might go about doing it: (it's been a while though so Google is your friend.)
Get vmware player
Get vmware unlocker
Get something to convert the .dmg inside the .app folder into a .iso
Install macos on vmware
Use that to create a usb installer.